# Does Microsoft Edge render the same as Chrome now that it uses Chromium? When might it render differently?

Tags: google-chrome, microsoft-edge, chromium

I'm aware of Microsoft Edge now using Chromium under the hood. Can I assume that the way Chrome renders websites is therefore same as in Edge ? Meaning for development and testing purposes I no longer need both browsers to check functionality and rendering. I can just go with the new Edge and I can have the confidence that the website functions and renders the same on Chrome as well.

So far I haven't spotted any differences thus I'm asking if there are any gotchas to be aware of.

Comment: Note: Chrome != Chromium, so Edge != Chrome. Anyway, I’ve update the title to avoid that and better reflect the question body.

Comment: Chrome and Edge (as other chromium based browsers) are just forks of Chromium, so there is difference in some features implementations

Comment: But they do share same rendering engine, don't they ?

Comment: (I’m not sure why there is a close-vote about this being opinion based..)

Comment: Yeah, so I checked Vivaldi, Brave and Opera each of which are based on Chromium just as the new Edge and functionality and rendering seems to be same. That's great. Now one no longer need to install all browsers to check compatibility. You need only few. Firefox, new Edge, Safari.

Comment: (I would probably say that this is Needs Focus rather than Primarily Opinion Based - if there are differences, there might be many of them. I wonder if rather than asking for a list of theoretical things, you ask this question if you believe you've found on specific difference, and ask if that thing is down to different implementations of the same engine. That's rather more focussed, in my view).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Microsoft Edge (chromium) has the same rendering engine as Google Chrome. So, generally the render output is pretty similar in Microsoft Edge and Chrome.

But, since we could add specific styles for Edge or Chrome browser by using JavaScript. In this scenario, you have to use Edge and Chrome browser to test it.

Comment: Are you saying that I could use different CSS to target Edge or Chrome users using Javascript ? You mean using Javascript to check for user agent in the header of the request. Correct ?

Comment: Though ... You would have to have really good reason for changing styles depending on different browser. I can imagine certain styles may not render as desired so you tweak it.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the developer might be using JavaScript to check the user agent, and then add a different CSS style or use different javascript function.