# jQuery UI icons sprite overflows in <p:column selectionMode="multiple">

Tags: jsf, datatable, primefaces

I have a `<p:dataTable>` with `<p:column selectionMode="multiple">`.

```xml
<p:dataTable id="someAppDto" var="someAppDto" widgetVar="someAppDtoWV"
    value="#{someBean.requestedApplList}"
    style="width:96%" rows="100" paginator="true" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="300"
    selection="#{someBean.dvoList}" rowSelectMode="checkbox"
    rowKey="#{someAppDto.m_nDVOId}"
    paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
    filteredValue="#{someBean.requestedApplListFltr}" rowsPerPageTemplate="10,50,100" resizableColumns="true" liveResize="true">
    ...
    <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:10px;"/>
    ...
</p:dataTable>
```

The same code has been working since past 10 years without any issues. However since last 3-4 weeks, we see these weird icons in the checkboxes. It is not impacting any functionalities, Only creating confusions. So our end users want to fix it.

[image: image of checkboxes]

Upon checking the check box, the weired characters gone. But when uncheck, it comes back again. I tried to create a jsfiddle for this, but I couldn't reproduce. So posting screenshots from Inspect Element in chrome browser.

[image: Inspect Element from chrome browser]

Yes, I did delete browser cache and tried, no luck.

Comment: [Same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76759698/primefaces-5-2-pselectmanycheckbox-rendering-unnecessary-icons), facing this problem (PF 6.2), only on the latest Chrome or Edge, and depending on screen resolution. Removing `border-radius` or `background-repeat: no-repeat`, seems to fix it, but I don't know why. It occurs with every checkbox(ui-icon-blank), as you can see in your image it's the [second column](https://mostre.cab.unipd.it/index/static/jquery/jquery-ui/jquery-ui-bootstrap/images/ui-icons_454545_256x240.png) and if you reduce the width of the window, the icons change.

Comment: Most likely a browser update? Because the code clearly has not changed. @WoAiNii please put your suggestion as the Answer and I will upvote it!

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat I agree with you all regarding browser upgrade. But I wonder how come it happens in both Edge and Chrome browser??? No Code deployment since past 4-5 months. Whatever code changed, it was before 4-5 months and nothing related to this.

OK, Now this what I did, it is working in my local. I have not yet deplyed in Dev/UAT.

```
.ui-chkbox .ui-chkbox-box{
   height: 12px;
   width: 12px;
   background: #ffffff none !important;
   text-shadow : none;
   box-shadow: none;
   -moz-box-shadow: none;
   -webkit-box-shadow: none;
}
```

After:

```
.ui-chkbox .ui-chkbox-box{
   height: 13px;
   width: 13px;
   background: #ffffff none !important;
   text-shadow : none;
   box-shadow: none;
   -moz-box-shadow: none;
   -webkit-box-shadow: none;
}
```

Only changed the height and width from 12px to 13px.

FYI: The above CSS code is in our global .css file

I know it is NOT a good solution, but for now, it is working and users are happy. I will still look for a better solution

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62038333/does-microsoft-edge-render-the-same-as-chrome-now-that-it-uses-chromium-when-mi